# Почему не сохраняются деньги после смерти в значении_monetT unity 3d

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
public TMP_Text _text;
public static int _score = 0;
public static int _scoreT = 3;
public TMP_Text _textT;
public GameObject _restartGame;
public TMP_Text _money;
public int _moneyT;
private bool _moneyUp = false;


private void Start()
{
    _restartGame.SetActive(false);
    _moneyT = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money", 0);
}
private void Update()
{
    _text.text = "$" + _score;
    _textT.text = "Осталось жизней: " + _scoreT;
    if (_scoreT == 0 && !_moneyUp)
    {
        _restartGame.SetActive(true);
        _moneyT += _score;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", _moneyT);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        _moneyUp = true;
    }
    _money.text = "всего" + _moneyT;
    Debug.Log(_moneyT);
 }
 public void RestartGame()
 {
    _moneyUp = false;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    _restartGame.SetActive(false);
    _score = 0;
    _scoreT = 3;
  }


}
```

Comment: не оставлено завещание?

Comment: У вас _scoreT не 0

Comment: я сохраняю количество денег и кладу в переменную _moneyT но при перезагрузки игры деньги сбрасываются

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей _scoreT взаимодействует с другим файлом, по этому так

Comment: Так вы разберитесь это "Money" или "Coins", а то вы читаете одну настройку, а пишете в другую. Хотя код в целом странный, может так и задумано.

Comment: @CrazyElf на счет money

Comment: @АрсланПсонуков Ну вы скажите - это нормально, что вы читаете одну настройку `_moneyT = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money", 0);`, а пишете в другую `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", _moneyT);`? Переменная - одна, а название настроек - разное.

Comment: Все понял, сам не заметил. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты считываешь значение Money, а записываешь значение Coins. И кстати, не знаю зачем эта функция существует. но `PlayerPrefs.Save()` писать необязательно, он и без него сохраняет